# Log4j - Logging into database

Tags: java, mysql, log4j

I am trying to setup the logs for my script into a database's table.
I am using the following properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, DB
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://<remote-mysql-server>/<DB-name>

log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

log4j.appender.DB.user=userid
log4j.appender.DB.password=pswd

log4j.appender.DB.sql=insert into logs(date,level,logger,message) values('%d','%p','%c{3}:%L','%m')

log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

I store the logs every hour. For the first run, it runs and logs as expected. But, for the next cycle, it throws an error as follows:

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I understand the reason for this, as the mysql connection is set to timeout the connection.

Is there any way in Log4j to make sure that before logging, I establish a connection and then close it after inserting the logs into the table ?
I tried establishing a connection right before logging in my script, but that didn't work for me.
I am using Ant to compile my Java script.

Comment: You will probably have to extend `JDBCAppender` with a custom class , and do the work of getting a connection by yourself '(and releasing it) . See the doc : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html , especially the parts where "pool" is mentioned. Here is an example (haven't found a better one) : http://www.databasesql.info/article/5862196881/